# SQL Injection MySql in php

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I've to make a small demonstration about how to make a MySQL Injection and how to protect us against them. I already know exactly how to protect our application for then, but I've some question about SQL injection.

A created a simple dummy website for the demonstration, on which I've added a search field. This search field isn't protected so subject to SQL injection.

I already made some example, like how to retrieve some global info on the database(version, current user, database name), inserting a `" 'UNION SELECT [MyInteresstingFields] From [mytable]; --"`, but my question is:

What is the next step? Is it possible to alter the database? How? I don't see, because mysql_query(it's a php website using cakePhp) only runs one request, so how alter a SELECT request to make a change in the database?(e.g. insert, edit or anything else, doesn't matter, it's only to show them what can be the result).

Comment: You can demo out how to count the number of columns, with a series of injections, sequentially increasing in parameter count until you match it. Yes you can ALTER a table or delete it if the user used to connect to the db has the privileges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you will use the injection to collect admin passwords (or the token emailed via a password reset page), then login to the admin part and do the stuff from there.

Comment: so it's mean that if password are hashed, there is no risk to alterate the database???

Comment: You missed what I said about the email reset token. The person uses the "I forgot my password link". This puts a reset token in the database, which is also sent via email - the cracker never gets the email, but he can see the token right in the database, and pretends he got the email, then changes the password.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the tutorial for testing the sql injection

[Sql Injection Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

Comment: yeah, but the only thing which can modify my website is the example with the $name_evil = "'; DELETE FROM customers WHERE 1 or username = '"; , and this can't work because mysql_query only execute one query

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query()` executes only one query exactly for the purpose to protect you from alter/drop/insert/update/delete statements if you are vulnerable to sql injection. But what if the vulnerable code is `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement? Then you can delete all rows, modifying the where, or maybe you could add another row, if you can add `'), (<values>)'` to the query, or you can update the access_level of the user, even if the original query updates only the password (if the password field is not escaped, and user enters `", access_level=1` for the password

Answer (score 2):

if your intention is to alter data in MySQL with sql injection without administrative privileges then you **can't **  . Although it's possible with SQL server .  . [image: below table let you to explain it]